Popup looking for su permissions to run script against Dropbox directory
I have noticed recently a popup asking for permissions after boot 1. See popup graphic. Now I did a cat on the file, it seems like it is just reaffiriming the user is xxx; however, I am suspicious of the set-group-ID permissions.
Code: Select all
~$ cat /tmp/tmpggoskie4
#!/bin/bash
chown -h -R 1000 "/home/xxx/Dropbox"
chmod  -R u+rwX "/home/xxx/Dropbox"
echo Done

What do you think? Is it legitimate? If not how do I determine the source?
Additionally, I did a search of the journal log for files associated with pkexec, here is what I found:
Code: Select all
~$ journalctl -b | grep pkexec
Nov 12 07:51:39 riomhaireob pkexec[2956]: xxx: Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/xxx] [COMMAND=/bin/sh /tmp/tmpggoskie4]


Nothing in your post indicates "set-group-ID permissions".
Other than that – the script seems somewhat reasonable. I recall Dropbox in the past having used this exact method for some other "self-repair" tasks, so it would not surprise me if it attempted to clean up file permissions after encountering an unreadable file in ~/Dropbox/ (where no such files should normally occur).

chmod  -R u+rwX the capital X is set-group-ID

No it's not. It has never meant that. (For that matter, u+ is not even in the 'group permissions' section.) Capital S would mean set-group-ID it were shown in ls -l output or provided to chmod as ls-style input, and if it were shown in the 'group' section of that output (and only if the file was not group-executable; it is lowercase s in the usual case where the file is both setgid and executable by its own group). For the regular chmod input, uppercase ugo+X is documented as "execute, but only if the file/dir already has at least one other +x", while set-group-id is g+s.

Thanks for the explanation. I did log a case with Dropbox and they said that they don't have such a script though.
